# Spring5 webclient make multiple calls dependent to each other with combination

Tags: reactive-programming, webclient, spring5

I have a simple java program that consumes two services and I want to call these services and combine the result that I have received and apply some checks.
I am quite new to spring reactive programming, so please let me know if there are mistakes in the code written

First Service Response(api/v1/employee/participation)

```
{
  "empoyeeResponse": {
    "participatedEmployee": [
      {
        "employeeNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "employeeNumber": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "totalActiveEmployee": 10
}
```

Second Service Response(api/v1/employee/:employeeNumber)

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":26,
}
```

I want to produce a service that returns a list of participated employees that exceeding age 30

```
{
    "participatedEmployee":[
        {
            "name":"jack",
            "age":33
        }
    ]
}
```

below is my try

```
public serviceClient() {
    this.webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/api/v1")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
}


public Mono<EmployeeListResponse> getEmployeeList() {
    return this.webClient.get().uri("/employee/participation")
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(EmployeeListResponse.class);
}

public Mono<EmpolyeeInfo> getEmployeeInfo(Integer id){
    return this.webClient.get().uri("/employee/{id}", id)
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(EmpolyeeInfo.class);
}

public Mono<Void> customService(){
    return this.getEmployeeList()
            .map(EmployeeListResponse::getEmpoyeeResponse)
            .flatMapIterable(EmployeeResponse::getParticipatedEmployee)
            .map(Employee::getEmployeeNumber)
            .flatMap(this::getEmployeeInfo)
            .then();
}
```

I want to change the output for custom service method to return Mono of EmpoyeeNewResponse and apply to check that Employee most exceeding age 30 
if not then the employee will not be added to the list

Answer (score 0):

Zero or One Signal

```
public Mono<List<EmpolyeeInfo>> customService(){
    return this.getEmployeeList()
            .map(EmployeeListResponse::getEmpoyeeResponse)
            .flatMapIterable(EmployeeResponse::getParticipatedEmployee)
            .map(Employee::getEmployeeNumber)
            .flatMap(this::getEmployeeInfo)
            .filter(user -> user.age > 30)
            .collectList();
}
```

or

Zero or N signals

```
public Flux<EmpolyeeInfo> customService(){
    return this.getEmployeeList()
            .map(EmployeeListResponse::getEmpoyeeResponse)
            .flatMapIterable(EmployeeResponse::getParticipatedEmployee)
            .map(Employee::getEmployeeNumber)
            .flatMap(this::getEmployeeInfo)
            .filter(user -> user.age > 30);
}
```